# executable file including a database

Tags: c#, database

i wanted to create single executable file with c#
with my database and application.I wanted to install that application in client machine which have no internet. how can i include my database into my executable file (.exe) to let the user in client machine save and retrieve information.
thank you

Comment: If you mean the executable itself and not the installer, the simple answer is you can't.  Otherwise you would be modifying the compiled executable.  The data store has to be a separate file.

Comment: Guess You cannot wrap your database with your application as exe and allow the client to save and retrieve.An alternative is SqliteDb(something like Database).you can read more about it here http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html and check if it matches your requirement.

Comment: Sounds like you are new to this. What are your requirements? Do you need a relational database in earnest? Or do you just need persistent data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simplest with single-file databases like SQLite.  Create the database, pack it up with one of the compression APIs, then include the result as a resource in your application.  On startup when the application fails to find the SQLite database file it can unpack it from the resource, save it to disk, then carry on.  From that point the user is working on a copy of the database on disk and can make whatever changes they like.

If you're using a proper SQL server of some sort it's a bit more difficult, but essentially the same idea.  Gather the data into a format you can work with, compress it and bind into a resource.  On startup if the database doesn't exist you create it with whatever scripts or EF code you need, then unpack the resource and load all the data into the database.

Of course if your database is very large then you'll have a lot of bloat in your application.  Better to pack the application and any data it needs as separate files in a ZIP or similar, then distribute the ZIP file.  User unpacks the ZIP file and runs your application, which finds everything it needs sitting in the folder it was unpacked to.

Honestly, I'd go with the ZIP file option unless you have a *really* good reason not to.